# Is every Folder a UIDFolder for JavaMail IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail

Using JavaMail with an `imaps` store, calling `store#getFolder` returns a `Folder` interface.

For IMAP, will this ALWAYS be a concrete `IMAPFolder` and hence a `UIDFolder`?

Or are there scenarios where it might be a different concrete class, and hence not an IMAPFolder? i.e. am I safe to blindly cast to UIDFolder for IMAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the included protocol providers, imaps always returns an IMAPFolder, which is always a UIDFolder.